# replace part of string based on user input python

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

```
word = hello
dashes = '-' * len(word)
guess = input()
```

If guess is `h` I want to replace `dashes[0]` with `h` because `h` is `word[0]` how would I check to see if `h` is in word, and then if it is, replace the appropriate `-` in `dashes` at the index guess is in `word`

Then given another `input()` and `dashes` is now `h----` and the input is `l` do the same but so that `dashes` becomes `h-ll-`

I hope this makes sense, best I can explain it.

I have tried the following after a guess is made and before another guess is given:

```
dashes = dashes.replace(dashes[word.index(guess)], guess)
```

but if `guess` is `h`, `dashes` becomes `hhhhh`
not sure why or how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`str.replace` replaces every instance of `-` in `dashes`.

You can instead iterate through the `dashes` after *zipping* with the full `word` and replace only the character in the same position(s) as the correct guess:

```
dashes = ''.join(j if j==guess else i for i, j in zip(dashes, word))
```

---

```
def update_blanks(guess, dashes):
    return ''.join(j if j==guess else i for i, j in zip(dashes, word))

guess = 'h'
dashes = update_blanks(guess, dashes)
print(dashes)
# h----

guess = 'l'
dashes = update_blanks(guess, dashes)
print(dashes)
# h-ll-
```

Comment: perfect, thank you and thanks for explaining why I was running into an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is a 'hangman-esque' game. Try this.

```
word = 'hello'
current = ['-']*len(hello)

guess = input()
for i in range(len(word)):
  if word[i] == guess:
    current[i] = word[i]
```

This is more efficient if you are planning to continuously update the current state of your guesses.

Answer (score 0):

Since string is immutable - I will decompose the word into a list of characters, replace suitable - and then compose into a word again

```
word_chars = [guess if c == '-' and word[i] == guess else c 
              for i, c in enumerate(dashes)]
dashes = ''.join(word_chars)
```